# How to remove empty text elements during cleaning of the document?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

My code is using jsoup cleaner to remove unwanted elements from the document. I have noticed that after the cleaning operation that many empty text nodes remain. Since they have no child nodes it should be ok to delete them.

Wondering if anyone has implemented a solution for this already...

Document output to string is below:

- - - - - li
- - - - - - text:
- - - - - - a: http://www.example.com//mobile/
- - - - - - - text: Mobile Apps
- - - - - text:
- - - - - li
- - - - - - text: Financial Products
- - - - - - a: another-link
- - - - - - - text: xyz Visual Data
- - - - - text:
- - - - text:
- - - - text:
- - - - text:
- - - - text:
- - - - text:

Comment: what is your clearing algorithm?? I guess you should remove whole elements from `Document` insteed of removing text

Comment: this was regarding jsoup cleaner: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing empty tags can be tricky because some tags are always empty (eg. `<br/>` and `<img/>`), others can affect the layout of the document even when empty (eg. `<p></p>`). Even worse, certain CSS configurations can cause almost any type of tag to affect the document layout (eg font icons).

If you can decide which elements your willing to remove, the following should work:

```
// Names of the elements to remove if empty
Set<String> removable = ....

// Parse the html into a jsoup document
Document source = Jsoup.parse(myHtml);

// Clean the html according to a whitelist
Document cleaned = new Cleaner(whitelist).clean(source);

// For each element in the cleaned document
for(Element el: cleaned.getAllElements()) {

   if(el.children().isEmpty() && !el.hasText()) {
       // Element is empty, check if should be removed
       if(removable.contains(el.tagName())) el.remove();
   }
}
```